# Pass proxy depending on URL prefix

Tags: express, nginx

I'm new to NginX and I have been trying to figure out how to do the following;

- example.com forwards to the express application running on port 3000 with the purpose of serving clients.
- dashboard.example.com forwards to the express application running on port 3001 with the purpose of serving administrators.

For this, I have set up the following configuration;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com dashboard.example.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# dashboard.example.com for administrators.
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name dashboard.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  }
}

# example.com for normal users.
server {
    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

The problem is that dashboard.example.com and example.com (as does [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) all forward to the client server running on port 3000. How can I make dashboard.example.com forward to 3001?

Comment: You have a duplicated entry for `dashboard.example.com`. Remove it from the first server block (at `server_name`).

Comment: If you don't need SSL for your `dashboard.example.com` app, remove `dashboard.example.com` from the list of server names in you first `server` block. If you need SSL and HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection, rewrite your second `server` block for using SSL like your third `server` block written (you'll need a valid certificare for `dashboard.example.com` doman).

Comment: @NullDev thanks for the reply, I have removed it and moved the second block up. However it still has the same effect.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks a lot, I actually do need HTTPS. I have just copied the second block and adjusted it with the correct values and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you always redirect to https (good job!), but you only listen for SSL traffic (port 443) on the server_name example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and have no proxy configuration for ssl on the dashboard. Try something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com dashboard.example.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# dashboard.example.com for administrators.
server {
    # SSL configuration

  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

  server_name dashboard.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  }
}

# example.com for normal users.
server {
    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Let me know if re-writing the middle block works for you. If the intention is not to have https on the dashboard for administrators, you need to remove `dashboard.example.com` from line 4 instead.